# React native push notification using firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification

I have finished installing initial setup for android ,[following this link](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/android) and now trying to setup Notification installation on Android facing errors tried a lot but not getting a proper solution.
My error is in below,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually looking for notification icons in drawable folder with the name ic_stat_ic_notification, and color values in android resource folder. You need to create those. If you wish to use default, just remove these from android manifest.

Comment: Yea you can. The channel id, is required if only you are going to have custom channels otherwise you dont need to set them. It will pick the default available.  Also, remember,  the notification icon may be just blank sqaure on push notification arrival if it doesnt meet android icon  standard. For my case icon came up only in samsung galaxy phones  but not in other phones. So I had to create notification icon as per android documentation.  Please upvote if useful :-)